# Как умножить все значения в объектах друг на друга а потом сложить сумму всех объектов

Tags: javascript

```
const shops: [{
            width: 10,
            length: 5
        },
        {
            width: 15,
            length: 7
        },
        {
            width: 20,
            length: 5
        },
        {
            width: 8,
            length: 10
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Нужно перебирать массив, и на каждую итерацию к переменной для суммы прибавлять shop[i].width*shop[i].length

Comment: ```shops.reduce((a, b) => a + b.width * b.length, 0)```